# Jira Markdown renderer module for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, markdown, jira

I am doing project which fetches tasks from Jira and displays them nicely. I render description from Jira as a markdown but I have issue with non-standard formats that Jira uses - for example they use `{color:red}This color is red{color}` which is not defined in standard Markdown.

Maybe someone had the same issue and found a solution?

Comment: JIRA doesn't use Markdown at all. It has [its own text formatting rules](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all).